# Julia: add to multiple arrays in parallel

Tags: machine-learning, parallel-processing, julia

I want to compute and add gradients to multiple arrays in parallel:

```
a = zeros(1,3); b = zeros(1,5)
a, b = @parallel (+) for i = 1:10
  f(a,b)
end
```

Where f(a,b) returns gradients of a and b (these are arrays the same size as a and b, respectively). Obviously the above method doesn't work because tuples are immutable, but I can't think of a way to do this that doesn't involve combining a and b into a larger matrix. Any ideas?

Comment: Overload a different binary operator to do the reduction you want.

Comment: Vectors of vectors do addition elementwise, so if `f(a,b)` returns `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5]]` or similar shaped arrays for each `i`, then `+` will handle it correctly. Additionally, `a,b = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5]]` will destructure correctly into `a = [1,2,3]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant, but this works:

```
function ta(t1,t2)
  t1[1].+t2[1], t1[2].+t2[2]
end

a, b = @parallel (ta) for i = 1:10
  f(a,b)
end
```